# how to use jquery to filter out children with class x

Tags: jquery

I have two scenarios I am trying to capture.

1) I want to use jquery to filter out all elements inside the jquery object who has a child with classname = myclass

2) I want to use jquery to filter out all elements inside the jquery object who's child element's innerhtml == ""

I was trying something like this

```
var Rows = allRows.filter(children(".myclass"));
```

and this wasn't working (and tried out a few other things as well, just dont have the code anymore.

Comment: When you say 'filter out' do you mean exclude from the results or only include those that match?

Comment: If you mean 'eliminate', try :not() - otherwise try .children()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `has` method:

```
var Rows = allRows.has('.myclass');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j8WUZ/2/

Comment: but it seems to work! thanks! Also, thanks for the !!, I had never seen it before but I found what it was here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript